# Need to report on data from Retrospectives - Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops

We need a way to access data through an automated way (either Rest API or some SDK) that is contained within the Retrospective Azure Dev Ops extension. Currently, there is an option to export CSV but the process is manual and limited to each Retrospective. Any ideas/thoughts?

Comment: Hi @Junior, how are things going? Is the suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please have try with it. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like as the following steps:

1. Run the API to get the information of project teams in a project.

   - Request URL

     ```
     POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization_Name}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview.1
     ```
   - Request Body

     ```json
     {
         "contributionIds": ["ms.vss-admin-web.org-admin-groups-data-provider"],
         "dataProviderContext": {
             "properties": {
                 "teamsFlag": true,
                 "sourcePage": {
                     "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization_Name}/{project_Name}/_settings/teams",
                     "routeId": "ms.vss-admin-web.project-admin-hub-route",
                     "routeValues": {
                         "project": "{project_Name}",
                         "adminPivot": "teams",
                         "controller": "ContributedPage",
                         "action": "Execute",
                         "serviceHost": "{organization_Id} ({organization_Name})"
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     ```
2. Run the API to list the retrospectives for a specified project team in the project.

   ```
   GET https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/{organization_Name}/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/ms-devlabs/team-retrospectives/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/{projectTeam_identityId}/Documents?api-version=3.1-preview.1
   ```
3. Run the API to get more details about a specified retrospective.

   ```
   GET https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/{organization_Name}/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/ms-devlabs/team-retrospectives/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/{retrospective_Id}?api-version=3.1-preview.1
   ```

However, we have not any available interface (API or CLI) to **Export CSV content**.

Comment: This works well thanks. However, using this I found out that data submitted "anonymously" is in fact not anonymous, as the API allows me to retrieve the userId for each "Team Effectiveness" vote...